# eclipse problem

Tags: eclipse

i got the alert as an error occurred 
when open the eclipse...
that log file contains the following error...

```
!SESSION 2010-09-03 11:59:03.157 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20090611-1540
java.version=1.6.0_11
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.dropins 4 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.171
!MESSAGE 
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.director; version="0.0.0"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1313)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1297)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1068)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:330)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.265
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate, org.eclipse.update.core.siteOptimizer, org.eclipse.wst.server.preview.preview, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.CodeGen, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.JMerger, org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.Generator, org.eclipse.emf.importer.rose.Rose2GenModel, org.eclipse.emf.importer.java.Java2GenModel, org.eclipse.emf.importer.ecore.Ecore2GenModel, org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.console.profile.StorageFileEditor, org.eclipse.jdt.apt.core.aptBuild, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.generator.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build, org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter, org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core.JavaCodeFormatter.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.http.ui_1.0.200.v20090113.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.server.http.ui 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.forms_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.annotations.ui_1.1.102.v200805140020.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.annotations.ui 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui_1.1.2.v201001222130.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.search_3.4.0.v20100608-0100-e3x.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.search 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.search 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.forms_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.db.generic_1.0.0.v200906020900.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.db.generic 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wst.xsl.debug.ui_1.0.0.v200904240436.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wst.xsl.debug.ui 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jst.server.ui_1.1.0.v20090421.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jst.server.ui 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2010-09-03 11:59:05.811
```

[image]

Comment: What was the message in the alert?

Comment: see the image i have uploaded

Comment: And what did you do, to achieve this? Is this a fresh installation or you made some configurations, upgrades, patches...? Please, be specific!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's missing the org.eclipse.jface.text plugin. Which should be in any Eclipse installation. Now sure why that's not there, but if you read the log carefully you see this sequence of dependencies and it points out which bundles are missing. Something that's missing that has no other dependencies is just not there.

Answer (score 1):

Check JDK in your PATH/JAVA_HOME environment variables - in my case it was too old for eclipse. I updated these variables to point at new JDK and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I would just download it again. It doesn't take long, and you can get a newer version that might help to avoid anything similar in the future.

Comment: i did that... but i want to know the reason for that error and how can we solve that problem...